# Symbol(s) not found & Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Visitor Framework

Tags: ios, react-native

Hi i'm trying to integrate BoldChat framework into IOS react native project.

After integrating via following steps

> Project target -Build Phases - Link binary with libraries - Plus
>   button - framework

While trying to build, im getting below error

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
      -[BC_SRWebSocket _innerPumpScanner] in VisitorSDK
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried  removing ,re-adding framework , it's not working. 
Even tried creating new project and integrating , still error is same.

please let me know how to resolve this. I have even tried similar stack overflow answers, still error exists.

Comment: Have you tried to manually add the framework?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this points to one or more missing references to frameworks in the section Linked Frameworks And Libraries in the Targets settings of the app in Xcode.

```
To find out which framework reference should be added:
```

- Right-click on the error in the build time errors
- list Choose 'Reveal in Log',
- Search in the log for 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64'
- A list of undefined 'symbols' (mostly class methods and properties)
  is displayed
- To find out which framework reference should be added, select such
  undefined symbol, right-click and choose Search with Google
- In most cases you'll end up in the documentation of Apple, which
  should give a clue about the related framework
- Add the framework in the section Linked Frameworks And Libraries by
  clicking on the + button.
- Build the app.
- If necessary, repeat this procedure for remaining undefined
  'symbols'.

  In my case **libucucore.tbd** is missing . Added that and error is gone.